# for every row in one data frame find the most similar row in another

Tags: r, nearest-neighbor

I have two data frames with Boolean values and numeric values. If needed the numeric values could be put into categories.

```
var1 <- c(400,234,199,45,77,19)
var2 <- c(0,0,1,1,0,1)
var3 <- c(1,0,1,0,0,1) 
df1 <- data.frame(var1,var2,var3)
var.1 <- c(78,147,670,200,75,17)
var.2 <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1)
var.3 <- c(0,1,1,0,1,1) 
df2 <- data.frame(var.1,var.2,var.3)
```

I want to find in `df1` the most similar row in `df2`.

I am aware of cluster analysis, which I could do for one data frame by itself, but once I have clusters for one data frame, how would I extract and apply the same clustering algorithm to the other data frame, so that both data frames are clustered in the same way? I also need as many "clusters" as rows in the data frame, which makes me think cluster analysis is not for this task.

Additionally, every row in `df1` must be matched with only one row in `df2` so that at the end of the process every row in `df1` matches to a different row in `df2`. This is tricky, because if taking each row in isolation in `df1`, the same row in `df2` might get matched multiple times, which is not desired.

Comment: not sure how to interpret the output of this

Comment: In the real data I have 4. I see where this solution is going but it appears to provide clusters of observations. What I want is a specific row to row match.

Comment: Ah, perhaps I am confused. It may be impossible to achieve this task without clusters seeing as the data is boolean.

Comment: @d.b repost your comment as an answer I will accept it, I believe it to be the most correct solution to this problem

Comment: This is not clustering. Just compute pairwise distances and choose the row respectively column minima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don'T have to do clustering, just search for the smallest distance. Take the first row of `df1` and `cbind` it with `df2`. This is easiest, if column names are identical

```
var1 <- c(400,234,199,45,77,19)
var2 <- c(0,0,1,1,0,1)
var3 <- c(1,0,1,0,0,1) 
df1 <- data.frame(var.1,var.2,var.3)
var.1 <- c(78,147,670,200,75,17)
var.2 <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1)
var.3 <- c(0,1,1,0,1,1) 
df2 <- data.frame(var.1,var.2,var.3)

rbind(df1[1,], df2)
```

the result of this can be examinated with `dist`. We are only interested in the first column of the result, i. e. the first `nrow(df2)` results.

```
dist(rbind(df1[1,], df2))[1:nrow(df2)]
```

evaluates to

```
> dist(rbind(df1[1,], df2))[1:nrow(df2)]
[1]   0.000000  69.007246 592.000845 122.004098   3.316625
[6]  61.016391
```

and `which.min` tells us, which of the rows has the smallest distance:

```
> which.min(dist(rbind(df1[1,], df2))[1:nrow(df2)])
[1] 1
```

So the first line in `df2` has the smallest distance to the first line of `df1`. You can put that into an `apply` or a `for` loop to do the calculation for each row in `df1`.

You have to answer the question though, how the distance of a mixture of Boolean and numeric values should be computed. There is no universal answer for that.

Comment: I see, in regards to how the mixture of boolean and numeric values should be computed, I would need to employ most likely a different algorithm than `dist` in conjunction with this solution. Because clearly row 2 in `df1` is more similar to row 1 in `df2` than row 1 in `df1` is. But if the distance already comes back as zero, there would be no score less than zero, therefore a for loop or an `apply` solution would not pair out every row in the first data frame to a different row in the second

Comment: In the example I gave, I compared only row 1 in df1 with all the rows in df2 and found the most similar one in df2. To do the same with the second row you could do `which.min(dist(rbind(df1[2,], df2))[1:nrow(df2)])` and find, that the second row of `df1` matches with the second row of `df2`. With a loop over `which.min(dist(rbind(df1[i,], df2))[1:nrow(df2)])` you could find the nearest for each row in `df1` which I thought you wanted. To define a better distance metric for numerics and booleans one would need to know much more about...

Comment: ...the substance behind those numbers. Maybe normalizing the numerics would be a good idea, maybe not. Maybe categorizing the numerics is a good idea, maybe not. With the information given, we really cannot tell.

Comment: I have just seen the addition that >that at the end of the process every row in df1 matches to a different row in df2.< This came after my answer and is not covered by my answer. Still you need to define a distance measure before finding a solution. Then you can compute all distances of all mutual row combinations and find the best pairs.

Comment: Yes, I can modify this solution to do what I need. Thanks. The first step would be to define a distance measure that can never go to zero, so that there can always be something smaller than it, to make sure a different row is paired out every time.